# moving exchange database and log files in SBS 2003 to a different drive or partition help

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, migration

assuming that the exchange databases are mounted if you use the system manager and go through browsing to a new location will exchange just move it for you?

i guess the xcopy option might be if you can't mount the exchange database? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only do this from ESM and yes, Exchange will unmount, move, and remount the mailbox store for you.

Comment: Glad to help...